# Background image smooth change

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried lot of things to make my changing background images to smooth change, but nothing work. Maybe someone can help me to implement some fade effect in my javascript ? Or just show me how to simply add effects ?

My javascript

```
var imageID=0;
function changeimage(every_seconds){
    //change the image
    if(!imageID){
        document.getElementById("myimage").src="./assets/imagesVR/VR_bg.jpg";
        imageID++;
    }
    else{if(imageID==1){
        document.getElementById("myimage").src="./assets/imagesVR/_DSC5362.jpg";
        imageID++;
    }else{if(imageID==2){
        document.getElementById("myimage").src="./assets/imagesVR/_DSC5178.jpg";
        imageID=0;
    }}}
    //call same function again for x of seconds
    setTimeout("changeimage("+every_seconds+")",((every_seconds)*1000));
}
```

My HTML

```
<div id="sliderB" id='myimage'><img style="width:100%;height:100%;"  id='myimage' /></div>
```

My Css

```
/* New Options */
    #sliderB {
        position:absolute;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        left:0px;
        top:0px;
        background-size: cover;

    }
```

Thanks and sorry for bad language, not my native.

Answer (score 2):

you may try some opacity stuff while putting one image on the other :

```js
var imgId = 0;

function change_image() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.slide')[imgId].className = "slide";
  imgId++;
  if (imgId == 4)
    imgId = 0;
  document.querySelectorAll('.slide')[imgId].className = "slide active";

  setTimeout(function() {
    change_image()
  }, 3000);
}

setTimeout(function() {
  change_image()
}, 3000);
```

```css
.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.slider .slide {
  position: absolute;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 2s;
}

.slider .slide.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide active" style="background-image:url(https://lorempixel.com/300/300/)"></div>
  <div class="slide" style="background-image:url(https://lorempixel.com/300/200/)"></div>
  <div class="slide" style="background-image:url(https://lorempixel.com/200/300/)"></div>
  <div class="slide" style="background-image:url(https://lorempixel.com/300/100/)"></div>
</div>
```

The idea is to change the **active** class from one slide to another and with the CSS transition you will have the fade

Comment: A little tip for your snippet, SO is secure, your images are coming via `http`, if you change to `https`, it will stop the warnings in the console.

Answer (score -1):

I hope it will help

Please change the css style as following

```
#sliderB 
{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```